# Bootstrap 3 - Modal Window Problems

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use Bootrap 3 and its Modal Window. This here is my test Code showing my problem:

```
<p><b><a href="#" onclick="return false;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-add-cart">SIMULATE ERROR</a></b></p>

<div id="modal-add-cart" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal-add-cart-label" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
        <h4 id="modal-add-cart-title">QUESTION</h3>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-small" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">STAY</button>
        <a class="btn btn-danger btn-small" href="new_page.php">CHANGE SITE</a>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

This works fine. When I click the test link the Modal Window appears. I can close the window via button and the x inside the windows. When I click again on my testlink the Modal Window appears again. But after the second time it is not possible to close that window. Does anybody have an idea how to change this.

Comment: The code that you have provided works here:  http://www.bootply.com/97128  Is there more code that could be causing the issue?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I could solve that problem while downloading the latest bootstrap 3 files.